# Which version TortoiseHG and Mercurial are compatible and stable for Linux RedHat ?

Tags: mercurial, installation, tortoisehg, redhat

I am thinking about installing Mercurial and TortoiseHG for our redhat linux server. I found out there are many package versions. I searched online and found out some people encounter incompatible problems when they install Mercurial and TortoiseHG. If anyone has successfully install TortoiseHG and Mercurial, may I know what versions you used for TortoiseHG and Mercurial ?

I used command "cat /etc/redhat-release" to find  the version of my linux is"
Red Hat ENterprise Linux CLient release 5.3 (Tikarga) and the bits number is "x86_64". Python is version 2.4.3. I do not need to use the latest version as long as they are stable and compatible.

Thank you very much,

Comment: TortoiseHG is a Windows Shell extension isn't it? Doesn't sound terribly appropriate for a linux server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TortoiseHG is mainly known for being a Windows shell extention, but there also seems to be a Linux version.

Take a look at the description on the [web site](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io) (I made the important parts bold):

> TortoiseHg is a Windows shell extension and a series of applications for the Mercurial distributed revision control system. **It also includes a Gnome/Nautilus extension** and a CLI wrapper application so the TortoiseHg tools can be used on non-Windows platforms.

and:

> Supported Platforms
>
> Microsoft Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7
>   Command line support via thg
>   Mac OS X port via source install
>   **Gnome/[Nautilus](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/nautilus) integration**

Note the link in the second part.
Plus, there are non-Windows versions on the [download page](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html).

There is also [this section in the release notes](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/ReleaseNotes#!matching-versions) which describes which TortoiseHG version should be used with which Mercurial version if you have to install from source (which seems to be the case whan you're using Linux, as I understood it).

---

*EDIT:*

Sorry, but I have absolutely no clue about Linux, so I can't help you about the installation. What I can tell you is that msi files are usually Windows installer files.
As I said, I have no clue about Linux, but I can hardly imagine that you can get a Windows installer to work on Linux.

Where exactly did you see the TortoiseHG packages? The [Nautilus link](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/nautilus) I posted above doesn't have any msi downloads (or I don't see them). The only msi downloads that I can find are the Windows-only downloads on the [download page](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html).

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your help. I checked the Gnome/Nautilus Integration link and there are tortoise msi packages. Can I simply install those msi files ? I googled the msi files and some people mentioned that it requires to install software "wine" first and install msi files. But since it is for GNOME/Nautilus integration, doesn't it mean we can install those packages directly ? Thank you very much,

Comment: I did click into the link and it showed the "Gnome/Nautilus Integration". In the context,I looked into the "package" section and it stated "You should find RPM and DEB packages for the nautilus extension on the Downloads tab." Thus, I looked into the Download tab and only saw msi files. The website is kind of confusing~. I still do not know where I can get the RPM package of TortoiseHG for GNOME/Nautilus. Sigh....

Comment: Okay, the download tab you mentioned does indeed only contain msi files. Look at the download page I posted (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/index.html), there are Linux links as well.

Comment: Thank you for help. I found the RPM packages and have some quick questions about them. 1) The package does not include Mercurial right ? 2) The version of Python(abi) is the same as Python ? 3) the Tortoise package includes python-nautilus app already ? Thank you very much.

Comment: As I said, I have absolutely no clue about Linux. I found all the information in my answer by just looking at the TortoiseHG webpage. So, unfortunately I can't answer your questions unless the answer is somewhere on the webpage. I think the packacge doesn't include Mercurial - what else would they need the "Matching versions" table (https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/ReleaseNotes#!matching-versions) for? I'm afraid I can't answer your other two questions.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will figure it out.:)